# Why do "linq to sql" queries starts with the FROM keyword unlike regular SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq-to-sql

Why do linq to sql queries starts with the `FROM` keyword unlike regular SQL queries?

Comment: If you use some intellisense provider while writing an SQL statement (ie: Apex SQL Complete, Redgate SQL prompt, or SSMS with a recent version of SQL server), you would see that the intellisense cannot suggest you something until it gets to the "from" - select * from. If classic SQL began with "from" then you would have intellisense there too. It was not an issue when "intellisense" didn't exist but with .Net intellisense plays a big role in code writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ mimics `Logical Query processing` in SQL you have:

```
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
11. TOP
1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE/ROLLUP
7. HAVING
10. ORDER BY
12. OFFSET/FETCH
```

But actually it executed like:

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE/ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
12. OFFSET/FETCH
```

Many people is not aware of it and made simple mistakes like:

```
SELECT col AS alias_name
FROM tab
WHERE aliass_name > 10;
```

And ask why it doesn't work. Because they assume that the order is like they write it. `LINQ` is better at this matter.

See also [Logical Query Processing](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf) and [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx):

> **Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement**
>
> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
>   order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
>   defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
>   steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
>   tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
>   columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
>   because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
>   columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
>   the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary
>   from this list.
>
> ```
> FROM
>
> ON
>
> JOIN
>
> WHERE
>
> GROUP BY
>
> WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
>
> HAVING
>
> SELECT
>
> DISTINCT
>
> ORDER BY
>
> TOP
> ```

Comment: There is great explanation about it in book `T-SQL Querying by Itzik Ben-Gan, Adam Machanic, Dejan Sarka, Kevin Farlee` in  chapter one why it has to be in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Some documentation regarding your question is available [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9afe39f4-7557-4b20-9723-88a8b4eb8832/strange-why-does-linq-query-start-with-from?forum=linqtosql) and they says that `It is more similar to "foreach"`. However [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397676(v=vs.100).aspx) is a good place to start and understand what is LINQ and different types of LINQ.

You will commonly find following types of LINQ everywhere. [Read here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions)

> 1. LINQ (Linq to Objects)
> 2. DLINQ (Linq to SQL)
> 3. XLINQ (Linq to XML)