# SQL Server - Where condition usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add condition to below select sql code.

```
select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
order by drivename
```

The result is ;

```
drivename   capacity(GB)    freespace(GB) 
C:\            120                36 
D:\            100                 7
```

I want to add like this : 'freespace(GB) > 10'

How can i add this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this.. `Temp table` and `CTE` may seems like the same but try to understand difference between them from [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/72998)

> **By using Temporary table**

```
select * into ##t from 
    (select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename,
    round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
    (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)',
    round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
    (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
    from #output
    where line like '[A-Z][:]%') as T

Select * from ##t where [freespace(GB)] > 10 order by drivename
```

> **By Using CTE**

```
;WITH cte as
(
select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE [freespace(GB)] > 10 order by drivename;
```

> **By directly using condition in where clause**

```
select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename,
round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
(CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)',
round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
(CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
And (round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
(CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)) > 10
order by drivename
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CTE or subquery:

```
;WITH cte as
(
select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE [freespace(GB)] > 10
order by drivename;
```

Second this is classic example of not understanding **[Logical Query Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668470/5070879)**

Answer (score 2):

```
select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX('|',line) -1))) as drivename
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as Float)/1024,0) as 'capacity(GB)'
      ,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0)as 'freespace(GB)'
from #output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
AND round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0) > 10
order by drivename
```

If you want to display only the C:\ information the above query would do.

Comment: @sezercan Try using `AND round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
      (CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as Float) /1024 ,0) > 10` but your code will be duplicated and uglier

Comment: @Abhishek You use only part of expression, calculating freesize has 2 lines