# SQL WHERE clause with computed value

Tags: mysql, sql

It appears that I cannot use a computed value in a `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM user
WHERE age >= 20
```

I get `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'`. A possible workaround is to use subquery but it overly complicate things?

Comment: Read about **[`LOGICAL QUERY PROCESSING`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668427/why-do-linq-to-sql-queries-starts-with-the-from-keyword-unlike-regular-sql-que/32668470#32668470)** and it will be clear why you can't use aliases in `WHERE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ***can*** use a computed value in a `WHERE` clause but not its Alias. You have to type the whole expression again

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) >=20
```

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column:
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

**[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but mySQL behaviour isn't like you think

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM user
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,CURDATE()) >= 20
```

mySQL WHERE CLAUSE only look into columns and not into alias.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot use a column alias in a `WHERE` clause. Same is true for a `HAVING` clause. But you can use a column alias in a `ORDER BY` clause (as long as it is not an expression to be evaluated). Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I could prefer to execute the above sql in the following way
Please note that I changed the query and re-code it in T-SQL
But I believe the logic of the SQL engines that will execute it the same

```
declare @curdate datetime = getdate()
declare @date20 datetime = dateadd(yy,-20,@curdate)

SELECT id, DATEDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,@curdate) AS age 
FROM [user]
WHERE dateOfBirth <= @date20
```

In WHERE clause I preferred to use a static variable whose value is calculated before. This type of WHERE criteria enables the use of INDEX on in our case dateOfBirth column. And this boosts the performance of the query

Otherwise, at least in SQL Server a WHERE clause like below

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,@curdate) >= 20
```

will fail the use of INDEX on dateOfBirth column and so the query performance