# MySQL AVG ... LIMIT returns total AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Table :

```
a | b
1 | 15
2 | 10
3 | 20
4 | 30
```

Query:

```
SELECT AVG(table.b) FROM table ORDER BY table.a ASC LIMIT 3
```

Will return 18.75 instead of expected 15.

How can I change the query to get my expected result (`AVG` value for a limited amount of rows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(b) 
FROM (SELECT b
      FROM table 
      ORDER BY table.a ASC 
      LIMIT 3) sub
```

**EDIT:**

Without subquery the order of execution is like:

1. FROM
2. AVG      (AVG is calculated using all values)
3. ORDER BY (but there is only one value)
4. LIMIT    (LIMIT 3 on one value do nothing)

With subquery the order of execution is like:

1. FROM
2. ORDER BY
3. LIMIT    (only 3 values)
4. outer query AVG (average is calculated using only 3 values)

More info: [Logical query processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668470/5070879) (TOP/OFFSET FETCH is the same as LIMIT).

Comment: Helped me a great deal, could you explain WHY it has to be done this way? Seems to me that the way AVG works without any connection to LIMIT is not very intuitive

Comment: @ndelucca Sure I've added detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT AVG(A.b) FROM
(SELECT `table`.b FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.a ASC LIMIT 3) A;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f42d/3)