# OFFSET and LIMIT are not working MAX in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit, sql-max

The Follow query in the PGADMIN is **giving me Nothing**,

```sql
SELECT MAX(time) AS MaxID 
FROM table_name 
where column_name like 'valu_name' 
OFFSET 1000 Limit 1000
```

Where as if I run the following query it **gives me output**

```sql
SELECT MAX(time) AS MaxID 
FROM table_name 
where column_name like 'valu_name'
```

But why? Why does the `MAX` function not work with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`?

What is the right way to do it?

The use case is to get the max time stamp of rows between the 2000 to 3000, that why I am using the OFFSET and LIMIT, the From to To rows may changes !!

Comment: That is because that query returns only one value, so it doesn ´t make sense to get the rows from 1000 to 2000 (they don´t exist)

Comment: `SELECT MAX(time) AS MaxID 
FROM table_name ` returns exactly one row with one column, so obviously `offset 1000` isn't returning anything

Comment: The use case is to get the max time stamp of rows between the 2000 to 3000, that why I am using the OFFSET and LIMIT, the from to To rows may changes !!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you give me a better idea how to do it ?

Comment: [Logical query processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668427/why-do-linq-to-sql-queries-starts-with-the-from-keyword-unlike-regular-sql-que/32668470#32668470) - OFFSET-FETCH is applied last. Second, without explicit `ORDER BY`  entire query  is underetministic(tables are unordered sets)

Comment: Please note that `like` without wildcards is equivalent to `=`. Note also the remark of @forpas about `order by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET` and `LIMIT` are applied after you get the result for `MAX(time)`, which is only 1 row.

If you want to get the max `time` of 1000 rows, arbitrary returned from your table since there is no `ORDER BY` clause, you should use a subquery that returns these rows and then aggregate:

```
SELECT MAX(time) AS MaxID 
FROM (
  SELECT time
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE column_name like 'valu_name' 
  OFFSET 1000 Limit 1000
) t
```